# Mysql representation in redis

Tags: redis

I dont have any experience in redis and i would like to use it to cache mysql php results but it getting abit complicated.

In mysql i have two tables

```
tbl_users: id, username, first_name, last_name
tbl_orders: order_id, order_name, order_date........
```

Suppose i would like to store both users and orders tables records in redis i picured a json looking like

```
{

  "users":{
           "1":{username:"jane", first_name:"user1", last_name:".."}
            "2":{username:"jane", first_name:"user1", last_name:".."}
              ...........
           }
    "orders":{
               "1":{order_name:"jane", order_date:"user1",....}
                "1":{order_name:"jane", order_date:"user1", .....}
             } 
       }

    }
```

In this case should i create two redis servers, one for users and other for orders or how should i go about this.

Comment: Don't create two redis servers. What key are you going to use to store these example results?

Comment: the above are a representation of how my data looks in mysql, i have a users table with many users, and also an orders table with several orders now i was wondering on how i can store the data in redis and yet be able to retrieve all users and all orders separately

Comment: Do you want to be able to retrieve all users, or a specific user?

Comment: all users and sometimes a specific user

Comment: You might want to look at my library. Helps you manage your redis keys and includes some real world usage examples https://github.com/imikemiller/Pkeys for redis examples check https://github.com/imikemiller/Pkeys-Predis-Example

Answer (score 0):

First, you should read [An introduction to Redis data types and abstractions](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro), to understand what Redis is and what it can do.

It sounds like you have 3 things you want to cache in Redis:

1. **A specific user**:
   This is what Redis is best at.
   `SET user:1 '{username:"jane", first_name:"user1", last_name:".."}'`,
   then read the user JSON back with `GET user:1`
2. **All users**:
   This probably isn't worth caching in Redis, since MySQL will be quite fast at returning all the rows in `tbl_users` already.
   You could use a Redis list (via `LPUSH` and getting all of them `LRANGE {listname} 0 -1`) to cache it.
   But you're just duplicating the functionality of a database table at this point, so I really wouldn't recommend it.
3. **Orders for a specific user**:
   Again, MySQL should be able to do this efficiently for you, with a good [index](https://use-the-index-luke.com/) on `tbl_orders`, but Redis can cache it using a list as well.